# Uninstall Per-User installation from another user account

Tags: windows-10, powershell, uninstall, windows-installer, wmi

I have an application installed with a MSI package as Per-User in a non-admin account, so the application is not on Program Files, but in User\AppData. I'm trying to uninstall that application from an admin account, but I can't.

I've tried querying WMI using PowerShell and invoke the uninstall method, but as the software is installed as Per-User, it won't appear in the query results from the admin account.

I've also tried using the registry. I can search the registry to get the uninstall string and call MsiExec with that (`MsiExec /x{ProductCode}`), but after calling that, I got a message form Windows Installer saying "**This action is only valid for products that are currently installed**". I also tried passing the path of the local package (`MsiExec /x C:\Windows\Installer\xxxxx.msi`) with the same result.

Is there any way to uninstall that application to the user from the admin user account, using command line, powershell, WMI, or even C#?

Thanks!!!

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, but I can't (or shouldn't ) log into the user account without its credentials, so I need to do it from the administrator account.

Comment: did you find any solution?